# Marcar los checkbox que tiene guardados el usuario en una tabla pivote en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo un formulario donde imprimo unas categorías y las etiquetas (subcategorias) que vienen de una relación, estás últimas son checkbox para poder seleccionar las etiquetas (subcategorias) en las que estoy interesado y realizar una búsqueda. Esos datos los guardo en una tabla para guardar la búsqueda del usuario.

Pero ahora lo que necesito es donde imprimo las categorías y las etiquetas (subcategorias), comprobar si el usuario tiene una búsqueda guardada y marcar los checkbox que salen de la tabla pivote.

Os muestro las tablas.

**Mi tabla `users`**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | personaje 1 |
| 2 | personaje 2 |

**Mi tabla `categorías`**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | categoria 1 |
| 2 | categoria 2 |

**Mi tabla `etiquetas`**

| id | category_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | etiqueta 1 |
| 2 | 2 | etiqueta 2 |

**Mi tabla pivote `búsquedas`**

| id | user_id | etiqueta_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

Mi modelo `categorias`

```
protected $table = 'categorias';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function etiquetas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Etiqueta::class, 'category_id')->with('productos')->whereIn('estado', [1,2])->withCount('productos')->orderBy('name', 'ASC'); 
    }
```

En mi vista imprimo así:

```
<form name="form" action="{{ route('web.filtrarEtiquetas') }}" method="get" id="filtrador">
@csrf
  <div id="accordion2">
    @foreach ($categorias as $item)
    <div class="card card_no_border">
      <div class="card-header card_h" id="headingOne2">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="mr-auto p-2">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <a class="btn btn-link btn_collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filtros{{ $item->id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="filtros{{ $item->id }}">
                <span>{{ $item->name }}</span> <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
              </a>
             </h5>
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
                
       <div id="filtros{{ $item->id }}" class="collapse {{ $loop->first ? 'show' : '' }}" aria-labelledby="headingOne2" data-parent="#accordion2">
         <div class="card-body pad_card_body">
           <div class="d-flex">
             <span class="btn_check">
                <label for="checkCategoria_{{ $item->id }}">Marcar todos</label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" id="checkCategoria_{{ $item->id }}" value="{{ $item->id }}"/>
             </span>
           </div>
                            
           <div class="row subcategorias">
              @foreach ($item->etiquetas as $sub)
                <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline margenChecks">
                    <input class="form-check-input aligned juegos cate_{{ $item->id }} prueba" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox{{ $sub->id }}" name="etiquetas[]" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox{{ $sub->id }}">{{ $sub->name }} <span class="cantidadPro">({{ $sub->productos_count }})</span></label>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               @endforeach
             </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        @endforeach
       </div>
      </form>
```

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con relaciones, hay que tener en cuenta que los usuarios `guest` no pueden guardar la búsqueda pero si filtrar, solo son los usuarios registrados a los que se le guarda la búsqueda, pero puede dar el caso que no tenga búsqueda guardada.

Alguna sugerencia, como puedo plantear esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publico mi propia solución.

En el controlador obtengo los checkbox marcados por el usuario:

```
$busquedas = Busquedas::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Luego en la vista creo una condición y en el caso que esa condición coincida marcho el `checked`

```
@php
  if(auth()->guest()){
    $condicion = "";
  }else{
    $condicion = $busquedas->where('etiqueta_id', $sub->id)->isNotEmpty();
  }
@endphp
```

Y dentro del input:

```
@if($condicion) checked @endif
```